# OnRecipientsChange or OnSend Event tracking

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'd like to automatically modify the body of an email before its sent based on the value of the `recipients` field. The `OnRecipientsChange` or `OnSend` events don't appear to be currently supported.

What is the recommended approach for dealing with these type of cases or is there plans to support these type of events in the future?

Answer (score 2):

The `OnSend` event has limited support: [On send feature for Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/outlook-on-send-addins).

It is currently in Preview and support is limited to Office 365 using OWA at the moment but it is on the near-term roadmap to broaden support:

> The on send feature is currently supported for Outlook on the web in Office 365 only. Support for other platforms is coming soon. Add-ins that use the on send feature aren't allowed in the Office Store.

Comment: It's good to hear an update about the OnSend event, I really hope broadening support means it will work for desktop apps and will be allowed in the office store.

Comment: The limitation is still there as of today. The docs also seem to have been updated and now they don't include the coming soon part: 

"The on send feature is currently supported for Outlook on the web in Office 365, Exchange 2016 on-premises (Cumulative Update 6 or later), and Exchange 2019 on-premises (Cumulative Update 1 or later). Add-ins that use the on send feature aren't allowed in the Office Store."

Comment: I've also created an UserVoice item for this: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/37530601-onsend-for-outlook-add-ins-on-desktop-client